# Delete Bluemix Mobile Data record using Node.js

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud

In the Bluemix **Mobile Data** dashboard I have a data class with a few columns:

- id
- name
- lastName

And I want to delete one of the records when the **id** matches the **id** provided, like this:

```
 function delete(request, response) {
     var idToDelete = "123";

     var item = request.data.Object.ofType("myClass", {"id": idToDelete});
     item.del();
 }
```

I see this error in the log after running the previous method:

```
 ERR     Object %o is missing field: [object Object] objectId
 ERR [Q] Unhandled rejection reasons (should be empty): [ 'Error: Object is invalid for given operation\n    at RestRequestError.IBMError (/home/........
 ........
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the code you used to create and save your data class object? The missing field in the error is something that the Mobile Data SDK automatically assigns. I hope creating the "id" column did not override that necessary functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the following?

```
function delete(request, response) {
     var idToDelete = "123";

     var item = request.data.Object.ofType("myClass", {"objectId": idToDelete});
     item.del();
 }
```

Comment: Note I changed `id` to `objectId`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the promise model within the SDK to ensure proper functionality? Try changing your code to:

```
var data = ibmata.getService();
data.Object.withId("<Desired_Object_ID>").then(function(item){
    return item.del();
}).done(function(deleted) {
    var isDeleted = deleted.isDeleted();
    console.log("Object deleted? %s", isDeleted ? "yes" : "no");
}, function(err){
    console.log("Error deleting object:" + err);
});
```

I also encourage you to use the promise model's full potential by chaining your requests for proper async functionality and accuracy, like I have above. You can find the whole list of operations and a good example of properly chaining the entire request [here](http://mbaas-gettingstarted.ng.bluemix.net/node#data-operations). See Data Operations underneath Mobile Data on the left hand menu. You can find more info on our promise model under Node.js Guide, Promises.